# MySQL syntax error with commas? - Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm trying to insert some data in a DB but I'm having some troubles. Currently I can't add data to my table and I don't know why.

I'm using some generic methods that you don't need to understand, this works in all my projects and don't have any error in any of this projects.

**Following is my method in the EscolaDAO:**

```
public boolean adicionarTurno(String turno) {
        String sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Turno (descricao) values ?;";
        ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
        params.add(turno);
        operacaoEscrita(sql, params);
        return true;
}
```

**The method "adicionarTurno" is called from my Controller:**

```
EscolaDAO modelo = new EscolaDAO();

public void adicionarHorario(Escola escola){

       for(Turno temp : escola.getTurnos()){
           System.out.println("Controle Turno: " + temp.getNome());
           modelo.adicionarTurno(temp.getNome());
        }
}
```

**And here's my Escola entity:**

```
public class Escola {

    private String nomeEscola;
    private ArrayList<Turno> turnos = new ArrayList<Turno>();
    private ArrayList<Dia> dias = new ArrayList<Dia>();

    public Escola() { }

    public Escola(String nomeEscola) {
        this.nomeEscola = nomeEscola;
    }

    public ArrayList<Dia> getDias() {
        return dias;
    }

    public void setDias(ArrayList<Dia> dias) {
        this.dias = dias;
    }

    public String getNomeEscola() {
        return nomeEscola;
    }

    public void setNomeEscola(String nomeEscola) {
        this.nomeEscola = nomeEscola;
    }

    public ArrayList<Turno> getTurnos() {
        return turnos;
    }

    public void setTurnos(ArrayList<Turno> turnos) {
        this.turnos = turnos;
    }

}
```

---

When I try to insert some values in arrayList and try to insert them in the DB (using EscolaController), I got the following error message (the first line is the "toString" of what I try to insert):

```
Controle Turno: Vespertino
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Vespertino'' at line 1

Controle Dia: Segunda-feira
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Segunda-feira'' at line 1

Controle Dia: Terça-feira
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Terça-feira'' at line 1

Controle Dia: Quarta-feira
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Quarta-feira'' at line 1

Controle Dia: Quinta-feira
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Quinta-feira'' at line 1
```

### What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
insert ignore into Turno values (?)
```

Note that:

- you need parentheses arount the values
- you must not have a trailing semicolon.

You'd better specify the column names, to make your code clearer and safer:

```
insert ignore into Turno (name_of_the_column) values (?)
```

Reading the documentation saves hours:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html